# How do I convert MULTIPOLYS into LINESTRINGS in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, geoserver

I have a table with a geom column as a geometry(MULTIPOLYGON)

I would like to create an additional column of type geometry(LINESTRING)

How can I do this using a PostGIS Query?

I need to be able to use the linestring in Geoserver to style labels along the line.

Comment: Would this help? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/49950/mulitlinestring-to-linestring

Comment: You could use [ST_ExteriorRing](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_ExteriorRing.html).  There is an example converting MULTIPOLYGONs to MULTILINESTRING.