# Error with contour plug in (QGIS 2.18.4)

Tags: qgis, contour, plugins

I am trying to use the contour plugin in QGIS 2.18.4 Las Palmas on Windows 10 (both are 64bit). When I choose the layer I want to use there is not problem. However when I select the field, I receive the following error message:

An error has occurred while executing Python code:

```
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mygis/.qgis2/python/plugins\contour\contour.py", line 349, in uDataFieldUpdate
    self.reloadData()
  File "C:/Users/mygis/.qgis2/python/plugins\contour\contour.py", line 360, in reloadData
    data=self.getData()
  File "C:/Users/mygis/.qgis2/python/plugins\contour\contour.py", line 799, in getData
    self.checkGridded()
  File "C:/Users/mygis/.qgis2/python/plugins\contour\contour.py", line 231, in checkGridded
    nr = ends[0]
IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Python version: 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 2.18.4 Las Palmas, 59c1d21

Python Path:

```
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python
C:/Users/mygis/.qgis2/python
C:/Users/mygis/.qgis2/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\Users\mygis\.qgis2\python\plugins\webappbuilder\ext-libs\jsmin-2.2.1-py2.7.egg
C:\Users\mygis\.qgis2\python\plugins\webappbuilder\ext-libs\gsconfig-1.0.3-py2.7.egg
C:\Users\mygis\.qgis2\python\plugins\webappbuilder\ext-libs\gisdata-0.5.4-py2.7.egg
C:\Users\mygis\.qgis2\python\plugins\webappbuilder\ext-libs\httplib2-0.9.2-py2.7.egg
C:\Users\mygis\.qgis2\python\plugins\webappbuilder\ext-libs\requests-2.9.1-py2.7.egg
C:\Users\mygis\.qgis2\python\plugins\webappbuilder\ext-libs\jsbeautifier-1.6.2-py2.7.egg
C:\Users\mygis\.qgis2\python\plugins\webappbuilder\ext-libs\six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg
C:\Users\mygis\.qgis2\python\plugins\webappbuilder\ext-libs\jsmin-2.2.1-py2.7.egg
C:\Users\mygis\.qgis2\python\plugins\webappbuilder\ext-libs\gsconfig-1.0.3-py2.7.egg
C:\Users\mygis\.qgis2\python\plugins\webappbuilder\ext-libs\BeautifulSoup-3.2.1-py2.7.egg
C:\Users\mygis\.qgis2\python\plugins\webappbuilder\ext-libs\BeautifulSoup-3.2.1-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado-4.0.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\certifi-14.05.14-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin\python27.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytz-2012j-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg
C:/Users/mygis/.qgis2//python
C:\Users\mygis\.qgis2\python\plugins\mgrstools\ext-libs
C:\Users\mygis\.qgis2\python\plugins
C:\Users\mygis\.qgis2\python\plugins\webappbuilder\ext-libs
C:/Users/mygis/.qgis2/python/plugins\webappbuilder
C:/Users/mygis/Desktop/IIUM/thesis/map
C:/Users/mygis/.qgis2/python/plugins\webappbuilder
```

Comment: Please write something about your data source and the projection you are using.

Comment: The data source is in shapefile format 
(EPSG:4326 : WGS84)
The field I am using is double with lengh = 1 and precision = 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After studying the data closely, I came to notice that the Shapefile was not a **point** geometry but a **multipoint**. I converted it using FME Desktop into a point geometry and now I am able to use the contour plug in QGIS.

Comment: From this link: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/55067/how-to-convert-multipoint-layer-to-point I have read that I could just had used QGIS to convert from multipoint to point, an alternative if you do not want to use FME Desktop.