# Multipoint vs point PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geometry

Is it normal to use the geometry type 'multipoint' instead of 'point' knowing that I use it to store only one point?

How can I convert from multipoint to point?

Comment: There is a good answer that explains how to check for multi-part geometries and convert column types from multi- to single geometries at: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28835/how-to-change-the-geometry-type-from-point-to-multipoint-within-an-existing-tabl

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To convert "Multipoint" to "Point", you have to use [ST_Dump](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_Dump.html), for example:

```
SELECT (ST_Dump(the_geom)).geom AS the_POINT_geom
  FROM MULTIPOINT_table;
```

On the question of using "Multi" or single geometries, I use this logic:

- if every geometry has different attributes -> Single
- if a group of geometries have same attributes -> "Multi"

Answer (score 14):

The easiest way to extract a point from a single-point `MULTIPOINT` is   [`ST_GeometryN`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeometryN.html):

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_GeometryN('MULTIPOINT ((1 1))', 1));
--POINT(1 1)
```

This avoids potential problems in situations where a set-returning function cannot be used.

There are some important optimizations that are available only to `POINT` type geometries (especially in earlier versions of PostGIS), so storing single points as `POINT` is good practice.  A `POINT` also uses about 25% less space than a `MULTIPOINT`.