# Geometry in PostGIS Table wrong SRID and type

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, srid

I have loaded some points into a table as Multipoint, they have come through with an SRID of 0. I need to change these to have a SRID of 7844 and also change them to be of type Point. There are other records already in the table with type of Point and SRID of 7844.

I have seen how to change the SRID from unknown to another projection here, https://postgis.net/2013/08/30/tip_ST_Set_or_Transform/ using ST_Set.

I have also seen that in PostGIS you can use ST_Dump for multipart geometries. I have also just found [Multipoint vs point PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86268/multipoint-vs-point-postgis)

How do I change specific records SRID and downgrade from multi to individual points in PostGIS in SQL without affecting the other records.

Comment: Use a where clause

Comment: is it acceptable here? I wasn't completely sure what was happening when using ST_Set if it was applying it to the actual geometry column or individual records.

Comment: 1) do the multipoint actually contain multiple points, or do they just have 1 part? 2) do you want to change the rows, or the column type?

Comment: they are all just single points within a multipoint. It will have to be row wise as there are some points in there with type of point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the general case where

- your table has a column `geom` of type `GEOMETRY(GEOMETRY)` (meaning that it allows for any SRID and any geometry type, which is the only way you were able to import those *MultiPoints* in the first place)
- your geometries *are* in fact referenced in the given CRS, but were imported without the SRID

you will need to re-insert your data in the way you intend to, as an `UPDATE` cannot expand a single row into a set of rows. PostgreSQL offers [data-modifying CTEs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) that break this down into a single statement:

```
WITH
    del AS (
        DELETE FROM <your_table>
            WHERE GeometryType(geom) = 'MULTIPOINT'
        RETURNING (<your_table>.*)
    )

INSERT INTO <your_table> ([<column_list>,] geom) (
    SELECT  [<column_list>,]
            ST_SetSRID(dmp.geom, 7844)
    FROM    del,
            LATERAL ST_Dump(geom) AS dmp
);
```

This will

- **find and `DELETE`** rows where the geometry type is *MultiPoint* in the CTE (improve the `WHERE` filter if needed), `RETURNING` them into the virtual `del` table
- `INSERT` a geometry dump of the deleted geometries in `del` back into `<your_table>` in the main `INSERT` query

**However:**

If your *MultiPoints* are **strictly single part geometries** (meaning that they always only contain *one* point), you are able to indeed run an `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE  <your_table>
  SET   geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_GeometryN(geom, 1), 7844)
  WHERE GeometryType = 'MULTIPOINT'
;
```

---

Some notes:

- if avoidable, do not have a generic `GEOMETRY(GEOMETRY)` column, especially without SRID constraint
- this is then better handled on import, likely with a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger, or before import in the client application

Comment: because I had strictly single part geometries the second part of this answer solved my problem. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you have MultiPoints and Points, both with SRID 7844 and 0, all in one column mytable.geom. Coordinates given with SRID 0 really are SRID 7844 and don't need to be transformed. This is a first shot:

```
SELECT
    st_setsrid(d.geom, 7844) geom
    FROM mytable, st_dump(st_multi(mytable.geom)) d;
```

(untested, as you gave no example data)