# Point vs multipoints when creating a view it automatically decided to go to multi

Tags: postgis, point, multipoint

I have a table with unique points, when creating a view it automatically decided to convert this geom to multipoints, so to do that it stores a second point with same details just varying the geometries by adding an additional point with the coordinates rounded to 2 decimals something like this for the whole table:
geom in the table:

```
POINT (395615.8290165778 244545.8441872464)
POINT (257873.01319132993 667424.9999337487)
POINT (458206.3635881541 262160.07226029166)
POINT (387805.8895183715 152154.898632466)
POINT (428487.0143444213 429645.00681228493)
```

geom in the view:

```
MULTIPOINT ((395615.82 244545.84), (395615.8290165778 244545.8441872464))
MULTIPOINT ((257873 667425), (257873.01319132993 667424.9999337487))
MULTIPOINT ((458206.35 262160.07), (458206.3635881541 262160.07226029166))
MULTIPOINT ((387805.88 152154.9), (387805.8895183715 152154.898632466))
MULTIPOINT ((428487 429645), (428487.0143444213 429645.00681228493))
```

I know there are function to cast between the two types as other post and in the postgis instructions shows.

[Multipoint vs point PostGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86268/multipoint-vs-point-postgis)

[Changing geometry type from Point to Multipoint within existing table in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28835/changing-geometry-type-from-point-to-multipoint-within-existing-table-in-postgis)

[Changing geometry type from Point to Multipoint within existing table in PostGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28835/changing-geometry-type-from-point-to-multipoint-within-existing-table-in-postgis)

is there a reason for it? is it better for performance to keep it like that? it seems to be wrong and I couldn't find more info about this behaviour.

This is the mock of the source for the view:

```
SELECT field1,
    field2,
    field3,
    geom,
    field1||field2||field3 AS normalized
   FROM table;
```

Comment: How did you create your view? I've never seen it do that

Comment: @IanTurton just added the mock of how the view is created, it comes directly from the source not intermediate tables

Comment: @jr.gcj that doesn't appear to me to be a view statement. Can you did a bit deeper for the SQL of the view? PGAdmin has a tab for that.

Comment: @BJW this is the query to generate the view is a simple select statement from teh source